# Is there a function $f$ that satisfies a certain property?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The question is whether or not there exists continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ such that:
$$\forall n\in\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\}, n\neq2 : \int_{0}^{1}x^nf(x) dx=0$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x) dx=1$$

'Summing' these integrals yields $$1=\int_{0}^{1}(1+x+x^2+...)f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1-x}f(x) dx$$ which is impossible so it would seem that there isn't such a function. Of course this argument is invalid since on $[0,1]$ $$(1+x+x^2+...+x^n) \not⇉ \dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

I've also experimented with some trigonometric functions, for example 
$f(x)=8\pi^2(\cos^2(2\pi x)-\sin^2(2\pi x))$ satisfies the conditions for $n\in{0,1,2}$, but it breaks for $n=3$.

Perhaps some kind of recursive approach would work? I'd appreciate any hints.

Thanks!

Comment: should the power of $x$ in the integral above be 2? Because you wrote that the integral with $x^n$ is $0$ unless $n=1$

Comment: Or should be $n \neq 2$

Comment: I meant $n\neq2$, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such function. Since you always have $\displaystyle\int_0^1x^nf(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$, when $n>2$, then$$(\forall P(x)\in\Bbb R[x]):\int_0^1P(x)(x^3f(x))\,\mathrm dx=0.$$Take $\varepsilon>0$. By the Weierstrass approximation theorem, there is some $P(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$ such that$$(\forall x\in[0,1]):\bigl|x^3f(x)-P(x)\bigr|<\varepsilon,$$and therefore\begin{align}\left|\int_0^1(x^3f(x))2\,\mathrm dx\right|&=\left|\int_0^1P(x)x^3f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^1\bigl(x^3f(x)-P(x)\bigr)x^3f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|\\&=\left|\int_0^1\bigl(x^3f(x)-P(x)\bigr)x^3f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|\\&\leqslant\varepsilon\int_0^1|x^3f(x)|\,\mathrm dx,\end{align}since this takes place for each $\varepsilon>0$, $\displaystyle\int_0^1(x^3f(x))^2\,\mathrm dx=0$, and so, since $x^3f(x)$ is continuous, $x^3f(x)$ is the null function and then, again because $f$ is continuous, $f$ is the null function.

Comment: Thanks! There is still some minimal work to be done since $\int_{0}^{1}P(x)f(x)dx=a_2$, where $a_2$ is the coefficient of $x^2$ in $P(x)$ but your approach solves the main issues I had with this problem :)

Comment: @nicomezi I missed that. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @nicomezi Me too. I will undelete it after having fixed it.

Comment: @nicomezi I have edited my answer. Thank you very much.